# Error deploying Dagger hilt with gradle version catalog

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am trying to implement dagger hilt in gradle version catalog, I do all the imports and it does them well, but when compiling, I get an error that I don't know why it is happening and I can't find a clear solution to this, could someone help me with this problem I have???

1. Error
2. libs.version.toml
3. gradle project
4. gradle app

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: as much as I find those images pretty, can we get some normal formatting for the code bits? might be more useful for copying purposes

Comment: It worked before you put everything in the catalog? If so I would try deleting the `.gradle` directory and force Gradle to reconfigure itself from scratch